# Responsive image: keep it's height, keep it centered

Tags: css, image, responsive

I have a full width image that scales too small at mobile phone size. I've tried adding `height:250px; width:auto` (in a media query), which gives a great size, but the image isn't centered. How can I center it?

Image is too small:

[image: Image is too small]

Image isn't centered:

[image: Image isn't centered]

Comment: can you post codes how you have added it , i mean css and html of that. it's background image or img tag?

Comment: <div class="headerimagecontainer">
  <img src="images/header1.jpg" class="img" /> 
</div>

Comment: .headerimagecontainer img {
        height: 250px;
        width: auto;
     }
    
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

Comment: Sorry (new to this!), the CSS is in media query @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)

Comment: instead of `width:100%` try `max-width:100%;`

Comment: max-width definitely centers the image, but also squishes it out of proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `background-image` with `background-position: center center;`

```css
.image {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1600x500');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```